# Landau Notation

Tags: math

Hy

How do i show the following:
f(n) <= f(n-1) +  f(n-2)+ .. + f(1) implies f(n) = O(2^n)

I think we can assume that f is monotonically increasing =>

f(n) <= n*f(n-1)

Comment: What have you done so far to try and solve this homework problem?  If you show effort and are stuck, people are far more likely to help you out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track

f(1) <= f(0)
f(2) <= f(0) + f(1)

|f(2)| <= f(0)|2^2|
|f(1)| <= f(0)|2^1|
|f(0)| <= f(0)|2^0|
Where f(0) is a constant

let x be a constant (equal to f(0))

Suppose that |f(i)| <= x|2^i| for all values of i <= n
Then f(n+1) <= f(n) + (f(n-1) + f(n-2) + ... + f(0))
==> |f(n+1)| <= |f(n)| + |(f(n-1) + f(n-2) + ... + f(0))|
==> |f(n+1)| <= x|2^n| + x|2^n-1| + x|2^n-2| + .. + x
==> |f(n+1)| <= x|2^(n+1)|
so case n implies case n+1

And by induction the claim holds for all n in N

And from the definition of Big-O notation, f(x) is in O(2^n)

Comment: Thank you: why do you distinguish between |f(n)| and f(n)?

Comment: so that f is absolutely bounded, if I didn't it could be unbounded in the negative direction

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by induction: f(j) <= c*2^(j) for all j < n

Then f(n) <= c(2^(n-2)+2^(n-3) + ... + 2^(1)) <= c*2^(n+1)

What I'm not sure is whether c depends on j, so whether we should write:
Then f(n) <= c_(n-2)(2^(n-2)+c_(n-3)2^(n-3) + ... + c_1 2^(1)) <= c*2^(n+1)

Comment: This is so close that I just finished it off for you